# Facing difficulty in understanding async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, event-loop

I'm a beginner. Got confused about async programming after seeing the output of this code

```
async function f1() {
   console.log('this is f1');
  let res = await f3();
  console.log('result of f1 from f3 = ', res['status']);
  console.log('end of f1');
}

async function f3() {
  console.log('this is f3') 
  console.log('returning res from f3');
  return {"status": 600} ;
}

f1();
console.log('inside global context');
```

Now my doubt is even though there is no async work going on in f3() as everthing is console logs and a simple return, why don't the output returned by f3 gets printed immediately in f1(), rather first the `inside global context` gets printed and then the console logs of f1() gets printed. What exactly did f3 return (I assume a resolved promise) and why didn't f1 immediately used it ?
If I'm not wrong f1 is still inside call stack when f3 returns a json

Comment: Promise resolution happens on a  clean stack. So no, the call to `f1()` yields the promise from the internal `await`, and then after that the Promise will resolve following everything else at the global level.

Comment: An [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) ALWAYS returns a promise. As stated on the docs *"Async functions always return a promise. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise"*

Comment: ("resolution" might not be the best term; I mean the continuation after `await`)

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly did f3 return (I assume a resolved promise)

Yes, that's correct.

> why didn't f1 immediately used it ?

Because of the `await`. Promises are deliberately designed so that if you `await` one (or call `.then`), the resuming of code *always* happens asynchronously. This means that as a developer you can be confident that the order of execution will be the same whether the promise is already resolved, or if some time must pass before it resolves. If this wasn't the case, it could result in some difficult bugs.

More specifically, resuming after a promise is achieved by queuing up a "microtask". That means that once all synchronous code has finished running, javascript will immediately run the code in the microtask. Nothing happens in between the end of normal code and the start of a microtask (eg, no browser paint, no setTimeout's going off).

If you'd like to know more about microtasks and the event loop, this talk is an excellent one about how javascript schedules everything: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0

Comment: Thanks for the info. What will happen if I tweak the code by a bit like this : 
`async function f1() {
   console.log('this is f1');
   let res = await f3();
  console.log('result of f1 from f3 = ', res['status']);
  console.log('end of f1');
}
async function f3() {
 console.log('this is f3')
  let res = await fetch("https://api.publicapis.org/entries");
  console.log('returning res from f3');
  return res ;
}
f1();
console.log('global context')
`
when exaclty the stack frames of f1 and f3 will be popped out in this case? And when will they be pushed back to again to stack ?

Comment: `f1` starts running and calls `f3`, which calls `fetch`, which returns a promise to `f3`. `f3` hits an `await`, so it returns a promise of its own. `f1` hits an `await`, so it returns a promise of its own. The global log then runs. The stack is now empty. Some time later `fetch` resolves its promise. A microtask is queued to resume `f3`. Once fetch is done with the stack, that microtask runs and `f3` resumes. `f3` logs and then returns, resolving its promise. This queues up a microtask to resume `f1`. The stack is now empty, so`f1` resumes. It logs and then resolves its promise.

Answer (score 1):

> If I'm not wrong f1 is still inside call stack when f3 returns a json

The thing is that `f3` does not return that, but a promise (as `f3` is an `async` function). That promise is resolved with the object `{"status": 600}`. Yes, `f1` is still on the call stack when that promise is returned.

<sub>NB: please don't call that a "json". It is a JavaScript object. JSON is a text representation and would have a string data type.</sub>

An important realisation is that when an `async` function (like `f1`) executes an `await`, it evaluates the operand and then **returns**! Its execution context is saved so that it can be resumed later, but it first returns, and it returns a promise.

Once the call stack becomes empty, the microtask queue will be processed, and that is where the job is that will *restore* the execution context of `f1` that was saved, and so only then `f1` will resume execution below the `await` expression.

Comment: `Its execution context is saved`

What does this statement exactly mean ? Or to put in other way which part of JS engine actually stores the execution context of a function

Comment: It is the same information that would be saved as when doing `yield` in a genetator.

Comment: Technically can I say that whatever code is present after await will be wrapped under .then()

Comment: Yes, and don't forget the `return`. You can imagine `res = await x; other statements; return y;` to be replaced with `return Promise.resolve(x).then(res => { other statements; return y; })`. The `return` is essential. Also `Promise.resolve` is needed, because the operand for `await` does not have to be a promise, but for `.then` you must have that method available. But there is more to it, as with `await` you can use a `try...catch` block that will also capture errors *after* `await`, which will not work with the `then` version, ...etc.

Comment: Can you suggest me some resources to read more about this (especially on async programming in js)

Comment: MDN has some articles, like [Introducing asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing) (broad), [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), ...etc (follow hyperlinks and use the navigation pane to find more). And you'll find a lot of useful Q&A on [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await+javascript)